# how can i achieve a time related task in my google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet and in column B, will put some task to  work on.
When i will put any task in column B and then i will select a date from calender  to complete the task like(within 2 days,5 days or 7 days),if i am not able to complete that task within the time which i choose in column E, THEN i will get a message like how many task are getting delay and need to complete.

Please help me on this.I have never done such task. Any help is greately appreciable
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jpkogQqEWz81MDHiyfnHnaJqyHj6Hzp8NhWOW1uG8OY/edit#gid=963841463

i tried insert time line and want to achieve if i am not able to complete that task within the time which i choose in column E, THEN i will get a message like how many task are getting delay and need to complete.

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION

You may want to look into [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that Google Apps Script offers which can send an email once every 24 hours to notify you of the tasks that you need to complete.

To access the script editor from the Google Sheet, click on **Extensions** > **Apps Script** from the toolbar.

[image: GOOGLE SHEET TOOLBAR]

You may use this sample script as a reference. It sends an email to your specified address and also counts the total number of tasks that are overdue in column `E` and do not have the status `Done` in column `D`.

### SAMPLE SCRIPT

```
function dueDateNotifier() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mainsheet");
  var gV = ss.getRange(2, 1, 4, 6).getValues();
  var nDate = new Date();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(nDate, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var dueDateValue = 0;
  gV.forEach((x, i) => {
    if (x[3] != "Done" && x[4].valueOf() <= nDate.valueOf()) {
      dueDateValue++;
    }
  });
  if (dueDateValue) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com", // Email account where you would like to be notified
      "Daily Notification for Overdue Work",
      `You have ${dueDateValue} task(s) that need to be finished immediately, ${formattedDate}.`);
  }
}
```

### REFERENCES

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))